# Sharing Authentication between Two Web Apps (session variable error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication, session-cookies

I am using the bellow code but I got session variable error in second application. How to resolve this issue.

in web.config

```
<machineKey validationKey="5533B5B116101E2620ED9F87A8DD3DB0456BC29031A62ED26251518DE620E7118A9943341AEDEA36E35C7E374553F2F93A0F43F1BE61FE4717246AF15C549737" decryptionKey="B68191FE6ACF945B33BB0D101DD892120B531C1B803FB0300D96F822ED7F19E2" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" />
```

in login page

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false);

var oCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, false);
var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(oCookie.Value);

FormsAuthenticationTicket oTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, username, 
DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), true, "");
string cookieStr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(oTicket);

oCookie.Value = cookieStr;
Response.Cookies.Add(oCookie);
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:4841/");
```

Response.Redirect("http://localhost:4841/"); is second application URL, it runs but got error on session variable which I have defined to record the user information.

Comment: There problem is because the session ID that's created by your first application doesn't exist in your second application. Your second application would have to manage the user info on its own. It's possible to share session info between applications if you use an external provider like ASP.NET State Server or Redis, but then you have to make sure that the session IDs are the same across applications.

Comment: Thanks howcheng. My session IDs in App1 and App2 are same. How would I share the session IDs between two app while sharing authentication. Any specific example plz?

Comment: If you give the authentication and session cookies the same names ("authcookie" and "sessioncookie" for example) and make it so they use the same domain (`domain.com` instead of `app1.domain.com` and `app2.domain.com`) that should do the trick.